# Middle-Earth Holidays/Festivals/Celebrations

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

In the west we celebrate many types of holiday. Christmas, Halloween, and Valentines Day, just to name a few. However, I would like to know if there are any similar types of occasions in middle-earth, and what (if any) Tolkien based them on.
I'm also quite interested to know if there were race specific holidays, or any sort of hero worshiping days.
Thanks.

Comment: 25 March, the anniversary of the downfall of Sauron, became a holiday in Gondor after the War of the Ring.

Comment: "The first day of the dwarves' New Year [...] is as all should know the first day of the last moon of Autumn on the threshold of Winter." -- Thorin, *The Hobbit*